# Render entire UITableView as an image! to share

Tags: image, tableview, swift4, render

I found this code, but it saves much, like 75% of the tableView, even off screen rows, but not the complete table. I was wondering if anyone understand why it does not render the full table, or how to change so it will render the complete table. Or other code that will reliably render the entire on and offscreen tableView?
Thank you in advance. Hope others can use this. I am in Swift 4. I can post an image if needed(just a long table image this produces, but not the complete table.) Maybe table-image is being made before table has fully loaded not sure, a guess as to problem. I'm newish to programming.

here is code I have:

```
  @objc func shareScreen() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width:tableView.contentSize.width, height:tableView.contentSize.height),false, 0.0)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let previousFrame = tableView.frame

    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.contentSize.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)

    self.tableView.layer.render(in: context!)
    self.tableView.frame = previousFrame

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.shareCellTable(image)
}
```

Comment: The tableview's frame is in the coordinate space of it's superview.  Reframe it to extend from 0,0 with a size equal to it's content size.

Comment: ok @danh glad to try, not sure code to do that Reframe though. If you can help, I try now and report back. thank you.

Comment: `CGRect(x:0, y: 0:, width: tableView.contentSize.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)`

Comment: I didn't quite follow that, but I'm happy if it's solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what I had. But that you I solved it. here is what I did:
added class variable:

```
var tableHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
```

in viewWillAppear added:

```
override func viewWillAppear() { super.viewDidLoad() 
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

in viewWillDisappear:

```
tableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
super.viewWillDisappear(true)
```

then in shareScreen() func change(just changed;  height: tableHeight:)

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, 
width: tableView.contentSize.width, height: tableHeight)
```

works great! I get the whole long table as an image :) I can post complete func if that is better? Here is long complete table outputted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofbd.jpg happy happy